# theano - speed test compared to numpy - BLAS libraries

Tags: numpy, theano, blas

I just managed to install theano. I did the speed test with the code below- and theano is a lot slower than numpy on the CPU. I presume that I might inadvertently have linked theano to the wrong blas library? (presuming that they would show equal speed if they would use the same library)? is there an easy way to check and remedy this? please let me know any advice - Many thanks in advance, W

NP time: 2.384000[s], theano time: 47.326000[s]

```
import numpy as np
import time
import theano
A = np.random.rand(1000,10000).astype(theano.config.floatX)
B = np.random.rand(10000,1000).astype(theano.config.floatX)
np_start = time.time()
AB = A.dot(B)
np_end = time.time()
X,Y = theano.tensor.matrices('XY')
mf = theano.function([X,Y],X.dot(Y))
t_start = time.time()
tAB = mf(A,B)
t_end = time.time()
print "NP time: %f[s], theano time: %f[s] (times should be close when run on CPU!)" %(
                                           np_end-np_start, t_end-t_start)
print "Result difference: %f" % (np.abs(AB-tAB).max(), )
```

Upon the advice of ali_m, i checked theano.config.blas.ldflags (which showed CBLAS) and i checked np.**config**.show() - which shows the text on the bottom:

following http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html (under troubleshooting) - i can disable the Theano BLAS (which indeed speeds things up) - but i am wondering how i can either achieve option zero or option two - and get theano to use the same MKL library?

```
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd', 'mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd', 'mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'libiomp5md', 'libifportmd']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include']
```

Comment: What are `theano.config.device` and `theano.config.blas.ldflags`?

Comment: theano.config.device
Out[62]: 'cpu'

theano.config.blas.ldflags
Out[63]: '-LC:/blaslapack -lblas'

Comment: OK, theano looks like it's linking against CBLAS, which is the reference BLAS implementation and is usually rather slow. Which BLAS library is numpy linked against (`np.show_config()`)?

Comment: there is a long listing of libraries - but they all nearly all start with mkl_ , which i presume is the intel math kernel. is it possible to run / swithc theano to MKL?

Comment: i played around a bit. Most websites refer to setting e.g. theano.config.blas.ldflags="-lmkl" (which didnt work for me). However - setting theano.config.blas.ldflags="-mkl" did work for me. However - i do not know whether this is the optimal setting. Further advice appreciated. i will edit the original question in the end

Answer (score 1):

To make theano dynamically link against MKL rather than CBLAS you could try the following:

1. Create the file `$HOME/.theanorc.txt` if it doesn't already exist
2. Add the following lines:

   ```
   [blas]
   ldflags = -L'C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64' -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_core -lpthread -lm
   ```

I don't have a Windows machine at hand to test this, so you may have to play around with the paths a bit.

Comment: Normally, the file doesn't use an extension, it's just `.theanorc`. (Windows doesn't allow this on Windows Explorer, but you can use notepad to save it without a txt extension.

Comment: Often there is a huge problem with spaces in the folders passed to ldflags. You can create symbolic links on windows without spaces in their names, to point to the original folders with spaces.